# Is Outlook.Application component still supported in Outlook 2016?

Tags: outlook, activex, mapi, outlook.application

I have some code that sends emails using the default email client on windows.

If it's Outlook, I'll use the "Outlook.Application" ole object, otherwise I'll fall back to MAPI.
This has been in use at multiple sites for several years, but now it is not working for a new client.

```
/* Pseudocode Delphi */
    client = HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\Mail
    if client='' then client=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Clients\Mail
    if pos('Outlook',client)>0 then useoutlook:=true;

    if useoutlook then OutApp:=CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
    else UseMapi
```

There are two problems with this approach using Win 10 and Outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.11901.20070) 32 bit

1. The return from the registry read is PackagedMail ... I don't know what this is and can't find anything about it.
2. Outlook.Application is not included in the registered classes
3. MAPI returns a MAPI 000001 incorrect function  error

I've found some clues online indicating that MAPI in outlook relies on the Outlook.Application OLE.

I just need to either know how for force it to install  the OLE class, OR register it properly for MAPI, OR to know if it's no longer supported and I need to find a different solution.

All I'm trying to do is to send an email with a pdf attachment. I found that Outlook's MAPI support seemed a little flakey and I was better off using the OLE, but if it's no longer supported or needs extra steps, I need to know.

If anyone has any detail on PackagedMail, that would be a bonus.

Comment: Do you actually have Outlook locally installed?

Comment: Yes, AFAICT. (Caveat: Someone else installed, and I only have limited access to customer site)

Comment: So does CreateOleObject raise an exception?

Comment: Yes, it returns an object not found error

Comment: What is the **exact** error? Most likely that means Outlook is not installed or that it is invisible to the current user (e.g. if Outlook was downloaded from the Windows Store).

Comment: How would downloading this from the windows store affect this? (Note: While this is starting to look more and more like an installation issue, it would be really nice to know why it wasn't apparently installed properly and how to fix it)

Comment: All store apps are installed in a sandbox inaccessible from the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer which resolved my immediate problem:

The Delphi Winapi.Mapi unit checks the registry to see if MAPI is installed:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Messaging Subsystem
  MAPI="1"
```

This was clearly visible and populated in Regedit, but not visible to Delphi due to [Registry Redirection](http:////https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector)

The actual registry key that 3 2bit applications see is stored here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Messaging Subsystem
```

which was NOT populated for some reason. Manually adding MAPI="1" into the WOW6432Node entry made the MAPI features start working again.

This still doesn't answer my actual question, but I thought it worth documenting.

NOTE: The MAPI value is a REGSZ (String) type.